# Saving and receiving URL not working

Tags: ios, url, core-data

I am trying to save a URL for a video to core data. To do this I am creating a string containing the URL, saving it to core data, and then retrieving it in another view controller. When retrieving it in the other View Controller, I get this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'` I have worked out that the URL being saved contains the URL, but when receiving it, it is nill. How would I fix this.

Here is the code to save the URL:

```
- (void) saveVideo {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    TimeTravelDetails *timeTravelDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeTravelDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *stringForSave = [self.videoURL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"String being saved: %@", stringForSave);

    [timeTravelDetails setValue: stringForSave forKey:@"urlString"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } else {
        NSLog(@"URL String saved");
        NSLog(@"String being saved: %@", stringForSave);
    }

    //NSLog(@"%@", self.videoURL);

}
```

Here is were I retrieve it:

```
- (void) getUrl {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    TimeTravelDetails *timeTravelDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TimeTravelDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSString *stringForURL = [[NSString alloc] init];
    stringForURL = timeTravelDetails.urlString;
    NSLog(@"The string has been recieved: %@", stringForURL);
    self.finalURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringForURL];

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are saving it in core data? Why can't you just save the video URL in NSUserDefaults and get it in your other view controller? Once you have NSURL you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: For starters you need to learn how objects work, especially instantiation. In this case the `stringForURL` is alloced and init'ed only to discarded and replace it in the next line.

Comment: using core data? i think its not the correct format...

Answer (score 1):

In the getUrl function you are creating a new core data object again (inserting a new obj to the database) and not querying the already saved data.
sg like the following should work for querying the db:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
 NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"TimeTravelDetails" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

 NSError* error;
 NSArray *saved_time_travel_details = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```